# "Warning: Error in : Tibble columns must have compatible sizes." when adding hoverinfo to filtered plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, shinydashboard

Updated:
Originally I was attempting to use plotly&ggplot with shinydashboard but have since dropped ggplot. I'm trying to assign hoverinfo data however, I'm now getting an error.
"
Warning: Error in : Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.

- Size 0: Columns `x`, `y`, and `color`.
- Size 2: Column `text`.
  i Only values of size one are recycled.
  114: 
  "

Below is my attempt.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

#______________________________________________________________________________#
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    df <- reactive({
        subset(iris, Petal.Width %in% input$Petalw)
    })
    
    # Extract list of Petal Lengths from selected data - to be used as a filter
    p.lengths <- reactive({
        unique(df()$Petal.Length)
    })
    
    # Filter based on Petal Length
    output$PetalL <- renderUI({
        pickerInput("PetalLengthSelector", "PetalLength", as.list(p.lengths()), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
        
    })
    
    # Subset this data based on the values selected by user
    df_1 <- reactive({
        foo <- subset(df(), Petal.Length %in% input$PetalLengthSelector)
        return(foo)
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(df_1(), options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 25))
    )
    
    
    output$correlation_plot <- renderPlotly({
        plot1 <- plot_ly(data=df_1(),
                         x = ~Petal.Length,
                         y = ~Petal.Width,
                         type = 'scatter',
                         #mode ="lines+markers",
                         color =~Petal.Length,
                         text = paste("Sepal.Length:",~Sepal.Length,"<br>",
                                      "Sepal.Width:",~Sepal.Width,"<br>",
                                      "Petal.Length:",~Petal.Length,"<br>",
                                      "Petal.Width:",~Petal.Width,"<br>",
                                      "Species:",~Species),
                         hoverinfo = 'text'
                         
        )
    })
    
}

#______________________________________________________________________________#
ui <- navbarPage(
    title = 'Select values in two columns based on two inputs respectively',
    
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               plotlyOutput('correlation_plot')
        )
    ),
    
    
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 6,
               pickerInput("Petalw","PetalWidth", choices = unique(iris$Petal.Width),selected = c("PetalWidth"), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
        ),
        column(width = 6,
               uiOutput("PetalL")
        )
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(12,
               tabPanel('Table', DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
        )
    )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you still plan to use `renderPlotly()`? Or are you just going to render a static `renderPlot()` with ggplot? The `renderPlotly` will try to transform a gpplot to a plotly object. It would be better just to use a plotly object directly if that's what you are going to render. I'm not exactly sure what your goal is here.

Comment: The iris data is not fully representative of the data I'm working on within my project but grouping the filtered data visually with color and having more data in the hover-over toolbar are my end goal. I've done similar in ggplot so I was attempting to stick with what I know. But I'm willing to use whichever is most functional.

Comment: I am able to color plotly fine, but the tooltip is more so why I was trying to use ggplot. my plotly attempts haven't had much success, my attempt._________

text = paste("Sepal.Length:",Sepal.Length,"<br>",
                                                   "Sepal.Width:",~Sepal.Width,"<br>",
                                                   "Petal.Length:",~Petal.Length,"<br>",
                                                   "Petal.Width:",~Petal.Width,"<br>",
                                                   "Species:",~Species,
hoverinfo = 'text'

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense to use ggplot for tooltips. ggplot was not designed for creating interactive plots so it doesn't have any native concept of tooltips. All the tooltip functionality is coming from plotly.

Comment: I'm definitely still a novice in R so pointing me in any direction is fine. When I try to use the code in my last comment I get the error
"
Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 0: Columns `x`, `y`, and `color`.
* Size 2: Column `text`.
[34mi[39m Only values of size one are recycled.
"
If I could figure out how to solve that using only plotly I suppose I'd have all I need.

Comment: When I run the code you supplied (without the changes to ggplot) I don't get any errors. I'm not sure how to replicate your problem so I'm not sure what's causing. Maybe edit the question itself to make it more clear what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: Updated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `text=` parameter needs to be a formula. The `~` doesn't just indicate a data column name, it's for unevaluated expressions. So a proper working example should look like

```
output$correlation_plot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
      data = df_1(),
      x = ~Sepal.Length, 
      y = ~Sepal.Width, 
      type = 'scatter', 
      mode = 'markers',
      text = ~paste("Sepal.Length:",Sepal.Length,"<br>",
                  "Sepal.Width:",Sepal.Width,"<br>",
                  "Petal.Length:",Petal.Length,"<br>",
                  "Petal.Width:",Petal.Width,"<br>",
                  "Species:",Species),
      hoverinfo = 'text'
    ) 

  })
```

There does seem to be a problem when you try to use `color =~Petal.Length` and you only have one point to plot. It seems this combination of events disables the hover text for some reason. This is possibly a bug.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the `~` I knew it was for unevaluated data but I didn't know to use it at the start of formulas!